# Check If sp_send_dbmail Was Successful

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a way to check if a particular e-mails queued using `sp_send_dbmail` are eventually successful sent from our Exchange server.  I've looked at the system tables `msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems` and `msdb.dbo.sysmail_log`.  `msdb.dbo.sysmail_log` seems to be the more helpful of the two; specifically, its `description` column.  From the tests I've conducted so far, it seems whenever an error occurs, a message in the following format appears in the `description` column:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2012-11-01T11:28:04).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Mailbox
>   unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay for
>   thisemail@email.com). )

This is enclosed with other rows that share the same `process_id`.  The description for the enclosing records are

> DatabaseMail process is started

and

> DatabaseMail process is shutting down

If an e-mail was successfully sent, the same 2 rows are recorded in the table, except with no enclosed rows between them.

So if I have a successful send, the following appears in the table

[image]

and if I have a send failure, the log records this

[image]

Are there other instances of how the entries could be logged if a send failed or if a send was successful?  For example, could it be possible that there are 4 rows of entries for a send (2 enclosing stating when it was started and when it shut down, and 2 enclosed stating the e-mail was successfully sent).  I've found no log records that diverged from the pattern listed above, but would like to be sure before I write logic based on this assumption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This link from Microsoft seems to be useful - [How to: Check the Status of E-Mail Messages Sent With Database Mail (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191278%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). See also related topics on Database Mail Logging and Auditing, Troubleshooting Database Mail.

Answer (score 45):

`sysmail_faileditems` will only get you the list of failed emails. If you need to see a list of successfull emails you need to use `sysmail_mailitems`.

Use the below query to get details for all emails sent the same date:

```
SELECT * FROM msdb..sysmail_mailitems WHERE sent_date > DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE())
```

And here is the complete query to get all the failed emails from the past 24 hours:

```
SELECT items.subject ,
       items.recipients ,
       items.copy_recipients ,
       items.blind_copy_recipients ,
       items.last_mod_date ,
       l.description
FROM   msdb.dbo.sysmail_faileditems AS items
       LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log AS l 
                    ON items.mailitem_id = l.mailitem_id
WHERE  items.last_mod_date > DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can check mail is started or not using GUI.
   [image]

2)you check email sending using following command.

```
 **Select *  from msdb.dbo.sysmail_sentitems order by last_mod_date desc**
```

[image]

3) **unable to relay in Exchange Server** :-
Launch Exchange Server Manager and move to Administrative Groups.
Select Administrative Group Name then choose Server>Server Name.
Now click on Protocols and Select SMTP.

Right-click on Default SMTP Virtual Server and select Properties

In Access tab, click on Relay>only the list below

Now check the checkbox “Allow all systems to successfully authenticate to relay regardless of the list above” and close.
....check with internal team for permission.