# Sent status database mail with gmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-mail

I have a problem with Database mail, which we are currently trying to change accounts for a database mail with a gmail account.

The problem is when I try to send an email with the wrong email account, the sent_status is always "Sent" in the log.

[image]

whereas before, when we used local e-mail, always showed a failed status when we tried it with the wrong e-mail.

Comment: Please see answers to a kind of similar question [Check If sp_send_dbmail Was Successful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14652916/716684) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will just trigger the mail through SMTP, But if you wanna track the delivery status then you should check on SMTP server, which has been used in Mail configuration.